# Salesforce CPQ : How to detect field changes and fire validation rules

Tags: cpq

I am still new with CPQ. So far we able to set validation rules if certain field contain certain value but we cannot set validation rules to detect field changes.

The requirement is to lock certain fields in Quote Line whenever checkbox in Quote is set to true. I able to create Product Rule to identify if the checkbox in Quote is set to true but how I can detect changes on certain field.

In Error Condition , there is no IS CHANGE operator. Is there anyone here using CPQ , how you guys detect the changes on the field and fire the validation rule.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to a bit extend the answer of *brezeton* [above](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/222882/31673).

In your case you need to create another field (kind of duplicate of your original field) and populate it before setting new value in the initial field. To achieve this, use the Price Rule. On your Price Rule use On Calculate or After Calculate event.

I couldn't find in CPQ documentation what rules are run first - Price or Product, but from experience I can be quite confident saying that Price Rules are running before Product Rules.

Then, create a Product rule where you compare two fields - one with old value and second with new value.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you should use a Price Rule to capture the old value and compare those fields